# Incluir ou somar elementos do tipo chave/valor em um array javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, array-push

Preciso incluir em um array objetos do tipo chave/valor com informações que vem do banco, mas se a chave já existir no array, o valor deve ser somado ao que já existe. Desenvolvimento em Angular

```js
/*A informação do banco vem assim:
  variavel[
  item1:10,
  item2:5]
*/
minhaVariavel: any[] = []

metodo(){
 this.dao.readRegisters().subscribe(data => {
    data.docs.forEach(d => {
      const info = d.data()

  //Antes de fazer o push preciso saber se a chave da nova info já existe na minhaVariavel, se existir o valor deve ser somado ao que já existe, senão ele deve ser inserido. (não sei se consegui ser claro)

  this.minhaVariavel.push(info.informacao)
  })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe mais de uma maneira de fazer isso, vou te mostrar uma delas usando um pouco de paradigma funcional.

```
// simulei essa variável como o resultado que vem do banco
const retornoBanco: any[] = [{ item: 10 }, { item2: 20 }, { item: 5 }, { item6: 25 }];
// aqui como exemplo considerei que já existia um valor no array
const minhaVariavel: any[] = [{ item: 3 }];

// aqui fiz uma redução e transformei um array em um objeto com chaves e valores
const retornoReduzido = retornoBanco.reduce((objeto, atual) => {
    // será utilizado caso a chave não exista
    const valorInicial = 0;
    // percorre todas as chaves do objeto atual e adiciona ao objeto de retorno,
    // se as informações do banco não estiverem agrupadas, as instruções abaixo
    // irão agrupá-las
    Object.keys(atual).forEach(
        (key) => (objeto[key] = (objeto[key] || valorInicial) + atual[key])
    );

    // retorna o objeto com as chaves adicionadas para a próxima etapa
    // da redução
    return objeto;
}, {} /* inicialização do objeto que será retornado */);

// percorre os itens existentes em minhaVariavel e incrementa
// de acordo com as informações de mesma chave que vieram do banco
minhaVariavel.forEach((elemento) => {
    Object.keys(elemento).forEach((key) => {
        if (retornoReduzido[key]) {
            elemento[key] += retornoReduzido[key];
            // remove chave-valor do retorno do banco para adicionar
            // somente os novos itens nas instruções finais
            delete retornoReduzido[key];
        }
    });
});

// percorre os retornos do banco que não existiam na minhaVariavel
// adicionando-os em minhaVariavel
Object.keys(retornoReduzido).forEach((key) =>
    minhaVariavel.push({ [key]: retornoReduzido[key] })
);
```

Deixei o código comentado falando o que cada parte faz, recomendo que você veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), para que nas suas próximas perguntas você tenha uma resposta mais assertiva.

**Referências**:

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Retorna esse erro na linha minhaVariavel.push({ [key]: retornoReduzido[key] }): O argumento do tipo '{ [x: string]: any; }' não é atribuível ao parâmetro do tipo '{ item: number; }'. A propriedade 'item' está ausente no tipo '{ [x: string]: any; }', mas é obrigatória no tipo '{ item: number; }'.ts(2345)

Comment: O que dá para entender com o erro é que a `minhaVariavel` é um array de `{ item: number }`, ou seja, tem que ter a propriedade `item`, mas pelo que entendi no seu exemplo, esse `item` seria dinâmico, vindo com chaves diferentes.

Comment: Exatamente, dinâmico. Eu copiei seu código com o intuito de entender, antes de implementar, mas de cara deu esse erro aí

Comment: Achei que já tinha portado para seu código, não me atentei ao `typescript`, coloquei o tipo da variável para `any[]`, agora deve dar certo

Comment: Muito obrigado, show!!